# Error loading javascript after installing Umbraco 4.7.1

Tags: dll, installation, umbraco

I'm working on an umbraco 4.7.0 project and I have upgrated from 4.7.0 to 4.7.1

It's worked like a charm in my localhost but I have a problem after installing it on the staging server :

When I connect to the **backend**, I have the javascript error : "Jquery(xx).mask(...) : function does not exist" and any key press execute the umbraco Save function.

The jquery mask plugin is used in umbraco 4.7.1 to add a date mask to the publish date in the property tab.

The Jquery mask plugin is new in Umbraco 4.7.1 and is being included by "DateTimePicker.cs" with [ClientDependency(ClientDependencyType.Javascript, "MaskedInput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js", "UmbracoClient")]

See : https://hg01.codeplex.com/umbraco/rev/d2304aa897d4

However, even if I delete on the Staging server the bin,umbraco and umbraco-client folders and replace them with the ones from my local computer (where it works) the bug is still here.

But if I change 
< compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" batch="false" targetFramework="4.0"> 
to 
< compilation defaultLanguage="c#" **debug="true"** batch="false"targetFramework="4.0">

in the web.config THEN it works...

Does someone understand what happened ? How can I make it works with compilation debug=true ??

Thank you very much

Fabrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody answered this question, I asked on the umbraco forum here :
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/25196-Error-loading-javascript-after-installing-Umbraco-471

The answer is :
"it's the outdated client dependency cache to blame (when you set debug="true" in your web.config this cache is turned off by design). Try simply to clean the contents of the client dependency cache folder (by default it's  App_Data/TEMP/ClientDependency)."